# Why when I Import .discomap from webservice it gets an Array instead of a List?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, list, class

I have a webservice, with this defined class :

```
[Serializable]
public class Parameter
{
    public Parameter()
    {
    }

    public List<MyObject> list { get; set; }
}
```

well, on another project/webservice, I import the references through discomap/wsdl, and I wrote this :

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void UpdateOrdineFoto(List<MyObject> list)
{
    Parameter par = new Parameter();
    par.list = list;
}
```

but it says "cannot doing a implicit conversion between `System.Collections.Generic.List<MyClass.MyObject>` and `MyClass.MyObject[]`

What does it means? Both using `System.Collections.Generic;` and are `List<MyObject>`...

Answer (score 2):

I guess you created your local model from the WSDL with some kind of tool (Add WebReference or something) - right?

And there you got it - it imported the list as an array - that's it - go and look for it, most tools let you change this, or you can change it by hand.

PS:
So you used Add Webservice - there should be something like this:
[image: change Collection Type]
Just change this here to use the generic list.

Comment: Yes, I've used "Add WebReference". Checking .wsdl I found `<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="list" type="tns:ArrayOfMyObject" />` ? I should change it as?

Comment: Right click the service reference then 'Configure'. You should see this dialog.

Comment: Also, there are some Array and some List, I need List on for this Local Class... not everybody. I should understand what I should write in the wsdl

Comment: try to change the generated code then - should not be difficult

Comment: as you seem to use another (version?) of the generation tool I cannot tell where exactly to find it - but you should be able to use the VS capabilites (goto definition, etc.) to just find the files for the classes/properties - then just use your C# knowledge...